# NameValueCollection.AllKeys.Contains always returns false

Tags: c#, namevaluecollection

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains(key)
```

always returns false, but

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params[key]
```

returns the value of the key.

Could someone tell me why this is happening?

In my case, the key is "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$username", I debugged and checked that in both System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.AllKeys and System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params, the exact key existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Params` collection is initialized with a case-insensitive string comparer.  When you use `Contains` you're not providing any comparer, so you're using the default, which will use a case sensitive comparison.

Comment: In my case, the key is "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$username" and I checked and it was in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.AllKeys

Comment: @user1149293 Again, see my answer.  Your two methods are using two different comparers, so they'll result in different matches.

Comment: I still don't understand. "different comparers" you said is just case sensitive or not. but in my case, whichever comparer should match the key, shouldn't it?

Comment: @user1149293 You haven't provided any indication that that's the case, no.  Given the behavior you're seeing, clearly your key and the value in the sequence match on one comparer and not the other, because one is more strict than the other.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question over and over again, I update my question a little. I still don't understand, I think both of Params.AllKeys and Params should find the key no matter what comparing method is used, no matter how strict the method is.
Could you give me an example, Thank you

Comment: @user1149293 if the actual value in the collection is "CTL00$CONTENTPLACEHOLDER1$USERNAME" but the value of the variable `key` is "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$username" this will cause the `.Params[key]` version to return a result and the `.Contains(key)` to not. To get them to behave the same you would need to include `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file and do `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.AllKeys.Contains(key, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`. The problem you are having and Servy is trying to explain is you have a capitalization error in `key`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you guys are trying to tell me. And what confuses me is that I debugged and checked and I didn't find any capitalization difference. I'll try the method you said

Comment: @user1149293 There's no reason at all to use that method.  Just use the indexer if you want to perform a case insensitive comparison.

Comment: Though I still don't understand what makes the difference, you are right, I deleted it.

Comment: @user1149293 I told you want the difference is.  They have a different comparer, and so the two collections have very different logic for determining when two objects are equal.  The indexer has the comparer that you want, and `Contains` doesn't (by default).